# Select/Deselect not working in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So, I have this cell in my `UICollectionView` which has two functions named `select` and `deselect` but they are not changing the `UILabel` which is in the `Cell`.
Here is the `Cell`

```
class SeatsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    private var length: CGFloat = 60
    var seat = 1

    private var seatUILable: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        seatUILable = getUnSelectedUILable()
        self.addSubview(seatUILable)

        seatUILable.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        seatUILable.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        seatUILable.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        seatUILable.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: length).isActive = true
        seatUILable.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: length).isActive = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        seatUILable.text = String(seat)

        // Keep the first always selected
        if seat == 1 {
            select()
        }
    }

    func select() {
        self.seatUILable = getSelectedUILable()
    }

    func deselect() {
        self.seatUILable = getUnSelectedUILable()
    }

    private func getSelectedUILable()-> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.appBlueLight()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return label
    }

    private func getUnSelectedUILable()-> UILabel {
        let label = getSelectedUILable()
        label.textColor = UIColor.appBlueLight()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 30, height: 30)
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        label.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.appBlueLight().cgColor
        return label
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm calling those functions.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Deselect the previous one
        let currentlySelectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: viewModel.currentlySelected) as! SeatsCollectionViewCell
        currentlySelectedCell.deselect()
        let clickedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! SeatsCollectionViewCell
        clickedCell.select()
    }
```

Comment: Is multiple selection allowed? If not, you can easily manage it with `didSelect` and `didDeSelect` delegate methdods.

Comment: @KeshuR. no multiple selections is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the `cellForItem` inside `didSelect` will return nil if the cell is not visible in the `UICollectionView`. For example: If the cell to be deselected is offscreen, then the method will not work as the cell is not present inside the `UICollectionView` at that point.

To make sure it stays deselected you will have to set the cell to be deselected inside `cellForRow` as well.

Another point that seems weird to me is that why are you creating a **new** `UILabel` on every state change? You should just modify the properties of one `UILabel` depending on the state.

I would suggest keep all cell states as deselected in `prepareForReuse` and in `cellForRow`, select them. Apart from doing that in `didSelect` of course.

Comment: If I click on the item which is on the screen it's also not working for that.

Comment: Well according to `layoutSubviews`, your seat 1 will be always selected. And you never update that value that I can see. So I'm a bit confused how the selection actually works. Maybe that is conflicting with your `didSelect` logic too?

Comment: Yeah, seat 1 should be selected but it's also sowing as `UnSelectedUILable`.

Comment: Can you add `cellForRow` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage it with `didSelect` and `didDeSelect` delegate methods. So when you tap a cell, it will call didSelect method and you can change your label text. Also, when you tapped that cell, if any cell is already selected, `didDeselect` methods will automatically get called.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YourCell
      cell.label.text = "Selected"
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.label.text = "Select"
}
```

Comment: Let me try that real quick.

Comment: Also dont forget to do this in viewDidLoad-         `yourCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false`

Comment: My function ain't working. They are being called but not working.

Comment: did you set `yourCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false` ?

Comment: Yes, I absolutely did! `select` and `deselect` cell function are not working.

Comment: Dude in your `getSelectedUILable()` and `getUnSelectedUILable` functions, you are creating a new label everytime .. you should replace `label` in your functions to `self. seatUILable` and remove that `let label = UILabel()` line from both the functions.